# How to determine what number to use with set.seed() while using the elbow method in R

Tags: r, k-means

I have a dataset of

```
customer | income(k) | spend (k)
  value      value       value
```

The data set has 40 entries.
I am using the elbow method to try and figure out how many clusters to use.
My question is how do I determine what number to use with `set.seed()`?

code is below:

```
set.seed(?)
wcss = vector()
for (i in 1:10) wcss[i] = sum(kmeans(new_dataset, i)$withinss)
plot(1:10,
      wcss,
      type = 'b',
      main = paste('The Elbow Method'),
      xlab = 'Number of clusters',
      ylab = 'WCSS')
```

Comment: I don't think seed has any effect on the result in R(apparently does in python). It's mainly for reproducibility and you can safely(I think) choose any seed.

Comment: `set.seed()` is used to achieve repeatability when using functions that generate random values. The number you choose should not have any relevant impact on your results.

Comment: Thanks, I was just worried picking randomly might be affecting the results. I had seen some comments of the same in a Python forum somewhere. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: @NelsonGon The random seed fundamentally fulfils the same purpose in R and Python and, depending on which generator you’re using, may impact the output (in particular when the seed has insufficient information to seed the entire state of the generator).